# Create a nodejs app in oracle cloud ubuntu instance

Tags: node.js, oracle, ubuntu, deployment, cloud

I just create my oracle cloud ubuntu instance and I want to run a hello world Nodejs application and make it accessible to the internet.

But the problem is  when I try to access it from my browser (http://public-ip-address:3000) doesn't work works.
I followed  this  instruction  " https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cd90d1ed3c462fe3bddd11bf8953a896 "
but it doesn't work too

this is my app.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the PM2 logs? Also, when you said it didn't work, what HTTP status code does it return? Does the firewall configuration allow inbound traffic to port 300?

Comment: the problem was  in the instance network settings, I didn't allow HTTP access

Comment: But is port 3000 open in the firewall setting?